# MAKE problems in Android Project enabled with cocos2dx - "No rule to make target"?

Tags: android, makefile, cocos2d-x

**BACKGROUND:** 
I'm following a tutorial online:  [Game apps in Android by Todd Perkins](http://www.lynda.com/Android-tutorials/Building-Monetizing-Game-Apps-Android/107169-2.html)
 - It's been very straightforward other than the hiccups that come with setting up NDK with eclipse, which I've managed to solve.

**Problem:**
I'm stuck at the point where I want my cocos2dx code to respond to a touch event and based on that, call Java android code from an activity.

I've added a bunch of screen shots below to show you how I've set everything up:

**When I run build_native.sh:**

[image]

Now I've made sure that I've linked my folders correctly in the project.

**Below is a screen shot of the "linked" JNI folder(jni_linked), along with JniURL.cpp and JniURL.h:**

[image]

**and here's what my Android.mk file looks like:**

[image]

I've double/triple checked the path of my Jni folder and it is:

C:\Users\DarkRaveDev\Documents\cocos2d-x-2.0.1\cocos2dx\platform\android\jni

**Do I need to change the Android.mk file to have this line:**

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := helloworld/main.cpp \
               ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
               ../../jni_linked/JniURL.cpp \
               ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp
```

Comment: did you add the NDK path in built_native.sh file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably treating:

```
/../../../cocos2dx/platform/android/jni/JniURL.cpp \
```

as starting with an absolute path instead of a relative path.  It probably should be:

```
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2dx/platform/android/jni/JniURL.cpp \
```

or maybe:

```
../../../cocos2dx/platform/android/jni/JniURL.cpp \
```

Comment: Yes that seemed to be the problem - Silly me. I used your second suggestion.